# I am receiving an error saying Unexpected EOF while parsing?

Tags: python

I am using a Book called Python programming: An introduction to computer programming and I am stuck in a programming exercise in chapter 10. It asks for a program that displays a playing card after the user inserts the value of the card and its suit.  Also, I should be using 3 methods plus two constructors, here they are:

```
__init__(self, rank, suit):
getRank(self)
getSuit(self)
BJValue(self)
__str__(self)
```

However, as I run it an error is displayed..... 
Here is my work:

```
from random import randrange 

class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):# This constructor creates the corresponding card according to their ranks:
        self.rank = rank           # "d"=diamonts, "c"=clubs, "h"=hearts, or
"s"=spades
        self.suit = suit

    def getRank(self):# Returns the rank of the card.
        ranks = [None, "Ace", "2", "3",
                 "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                 "9", "King", "Queen", "Jack"]
        self.rank = ranks[self.rank]
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):# Returns the suit of the card.
        suits = ["diamons", "heart", "club", "spades"]
        # TRY TO MAKE THIS PIECE OF CODE MORE ABSTRACT!!!!
        if self.suit[0] == "d":
            self.suit = suits[0]
        elif self.suit[0] == "h":
            self.suit = suits[1]
        elif self.suit[0] == "c":
            self.suit = suits[2]
        elif self.suit[0] == "s":
            self.suit = suits[3]
        return self.suit# A suit in Blackjack means the symbol of the card.

    def BJValue(self):# Returns the Blackjack value of a card.
        # For example Aces count as 1 and face cards count as 10.
        while 0 < self.rank <= 10:
            if self.rank == "Ace":
                self.rank = 1
                self.bjvalue = self.rank
            elif self.rank[0] == "King" or self.rank[0] == "Queen" or self.rank[0] == "Jack":
                self.rank = 10
                self.bjvalue = self.rank
            else:
                self.bjvalue = self.rank  
        return self.bjvalue

    def __str__(self):# Returns a string that names the card. For example "Ace of Spade".
        print("{0} of {1}".format(self.rank, self.suit)
```

I'm sorry for my Englis but is not my first language.

Comment: Look at the line that the error points to. Does it look wrong?

Comment: It points right after the second constructor def __str__(self) where it ends with the format.

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: Missing closing bracket in `print("{0} of {1}".format(self.rank, self.suit)` line.

Comment: Thanks Chapner that was it, however, I am facing a problem when I run it I do not get the expected outcome. When inserted 1 and "s" I should get back "Ace of Spades" but "1 of s" instead...

Comment: @EmmanuelKofyAgyapong If you have different problem, ask another question. Learn more on [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: Łukasz Rogalski Hahaha sorry for that I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the close parentheses in the final `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to close parenthesis at the end of last line, there is one opening for print method, but not closing at the end.